# ReInstall Sitecore IIS can't resolve host (with ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)

Tags: iis, sitecore, sitecore8

I decided to reinstall Sitecore 8 instance via wizard, I have removed instance and install a new one with the same name XYZ.
but after reinstall it I am getting an error in browser - ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED
I checked IIS binding, I checked hosts file, reset DNS, restart PC and etc I still get this error in any browsers.
How I can fix it? What is the issue?

Comment: How is the domain name controled? Is it something that should be specified in the hosts file, or a domain that you're expecting to come from a DNS server?

Comment: it is local environment controlled via host

Comment: Does this happen for Sitecore site only? Looks like sometimes it is [a Chrome issue](http://superuser.com/a/876551/49217)

Comment: with all website under local iis, but it happened after sitecore reinstall. anyway I have found how to fix it https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2823477

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2823477 but I can't understend how sitecore installer can change it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, the process of site resolution goes in the following consequence:

1. DNS - find ip address by the hostname (from request header)
2. Access IIS with that IP (and port if not default 80)
3. IIS checks bindings by hostname from header and serves corresponding website.
4. Website being resolved has (merged) web.config in root folder. It has  node with all sites served by current Sitecore instance, being listed. Order does matter! First successful match (by hostname or port or default) works it out.
5. Site being found on previous step has startItem property which is your Sitecore item served by dafault.

Please go and carefully check all those steps to see where it breaks. Also I have previously write a blog post, you may find it helpful with more details on that:

http://blog.martinmiles.net/post/how-websites-are-resolved-with-sitecore

Answer (score 0):

Do any sites work with a Local name configured in 'hosts'?

You may need to disable the Loopback Check in your tcpip stack. Windows uses this as a countermeasure for man in the middle attacks by default on many systems. A registry change is needed to allow a machine to refer to itself using a name that is not its own Hostname. Sorry, but I can't remember the actual key.